# Can we use lightning:input in production

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput

```
<lightning:input value="{!v.selectedValue}" placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" readonly="true"/>
```

Can we use the code above in SFDC production? I see that this input component is still in beta from a long time. This code is working in sandbox environment, but am not sure whether this is going to work in production.

Comment: We are using it in our products that are installed in several customer orgs for a couple months now, so you should be save. With using the current API version (42) for your component, it should always be available.

Answer (score 3):

BETA features in salesforce needs to be carefully evaluated on its implications if salesforce does not go with a GA of the product .

The official docs specify below for any BETA feature

> As a beta feature, the feature is in preview and is not considered part of the “Services” under your master subscription agreement with Salesforce. Salesforce does not guarantee general availability of this beta feature within any particular time frame or at all. Use of this beta in your sole discretion and is for evaluation purposes only and not for production use. This beta feature is offered as-is, is not supported, and Salesforce will have no liability for any harm or damage arising out of or in connection with this beta feature. All restrictions, Salesforce reservation of rights and Customer obligations concerning the Services, and use of any related Non-SFDC Applications and Content, shall apply equally to Customer’s use of this beta feature. Salesforce may discontinue this beta feature at any time in our sole discretion. You should make your purchase decisions only on the basis of generally available products and features.

Hence i would really be hesitating to use that for Production application specifically if i am building an ISV application .

If you are a system integrator then worth communicating to your sponsors and Technology leads around its implications before trying to deliver an application with this component .

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work in production. It is still 'beta' because there might still be some bugs to be worked out, but for the most use cases, the component works fine.